# How to groupby with conditions in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table like below

| date | train | condition 1 | condition 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day1 | 1111 | true | 0 |
| day2 | 2222 | false | 2 |

.....

I want to group the train with date,

| date | train total count | train with condition 1 is true | train with condition 2 > 0 | train with condition 1 true and condition 2>0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| day2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

How can I achieve that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For improve performance comapre `greater` like `0` before groupby to helper column and then aggregate `count` with `sum` for count `True`s values in [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation), for new columns names with spaces is used `**` unpack trick:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['condition 2'].gt(0))
         .groupby('date')
         .agg(**{'train total count': ('train', 'count'), 
                 'train with condition 1 is true': ('condition 1','sum'), 
                 'train with condition 2 > 0':('new','sum')})
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   date  train total count  train with condition 1 is true  \
0  day1                  1                               1   
1  day2                  1                               0   

   train with condition 2 > 0  
0                           0  
1                           1
```

Comment: what's the meaning of agg(**)?

Comment: why do we need ** for agg?

Comment: Actually, I found it If your desired output column names are not valid Python keywords, construct a dictionary and unpack the keyword arguments
.

Comment: what if we want multiple conditions here?

Answer (score 1):

try via `groupby()` and `agg()` method:

```
out=(df.groupby('date',as_index=False)
       .agg(
           {'train':'count','condition 1':lambda x:x,'condition 2':lambda x:x.gt(0)}
           )
     )
```

Finally use `astype()` method:

```
out[['condition 1','condition 2']]=out[['condition 1','condition 2']].astype(int)
```

Output of `out`:

```
    date    train   condition 1     condition 2
0   day1    1       1                   0
1   day2    1       0                   1
```

If needed to change the name of columns then use:

```
out.columns=['date','train total count','train with condition 1 is true','train with condition 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Print (df)

   date  train  condition 1  condition 2
0  day1   1111         True            0
1  day2   2222        False            2



df['condition 1']=df['condition 1'].astype(int)
```

Lets Try groupby agg

```
df.groupby('date').agg(traintotalcount=('train', 'count'), trainwithcondition1istrue=('condition 1', lambda x: x.astype(int)), trainwithcondition2gt0=('condition 2', lambda x: int(x>0)))
```

Outcome

```
      traintotalcount  trainwithcondition1istrue  trainwithcondition2gt0
date                                                                    
day1                1                          1                       0
day2                1                          0                       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .agg() method to apply different aggregation for different columns.

Try this:

```
df.groupby('date').agg({'train':'count',
                        'condition 1':'sum', 
                        'condition 2': lambda x: (x>0).sum()})
```

Output:

```
       train    condition 1   condition 2
date            
day1     1           1             0
day2     1           0             1
```

Notice that if `condition 1` is a boolean column, python considers `True` as `1` and `False` as `0` when doing the summation.